# Кодировка отображения имени файла в диалоговом окошке "Save as..."

Tags: asp.net, .net

```
CurrentUser.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
CurrentUser.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + myfile.Name);
CurrentUser.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", myfile.Length.ToString());
CurrentUser.Response.Charset = "windows-1251";
CurrentUser.Response.AddHeader("Accept-Language", "ru-RU"); 
CurrentUser.Response.TransmitFile(fileName);
```

Что нужно сделать, чтобы при появлении окошка "Save as" имя файла отображалась нормально, в данный момент **IE** кириллицу показывает иероглифами...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для **IE** нужно просто вызвать `Server.UrlEncode(str)`.
**FF**, **Opera**, **Chrome** в последних версиях всё нормально.

```
CurrentUser.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";

var fName = CurrentUser.Query("filename");

if (CurrentUser.Request.UserAgent != null &&
    CurrentUser.Request.UserAgent.IndexOf("MSIE") >= 0)
   fName = CurrentUser.Server.UrlEncode(fName);

CurrentUser.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fName);

CurrentUser.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", myfile.Length.ToString());
CurrentUser.Response.TransmitFile(fileName);
```